# What is the difference between Event and even class?

Tags: java

What is the difference between `import java.awt.event.*` and `import java.awt.Event`? Aren't they same import? I had to implement ActionListener and I was importing .Events and did not work. Later I changed E to e and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between import java.awt.event.* and import java.awt.Events ? Aren't they same import ?

No, they're not at all the same import.

`java.awt.event` is a package containing many classes related to events in the awt system.

`java.awt.Events` doesn't exist, but I suspect you meant `java.awt.Event` which is a class.  It's obsolete, there only for backward compatibility, and shouldn't be used.